# Python: Internal Information of Function calls and Automated Logging

Tags: python, logging, build-automation

I want to write a class that will show me the tree of currently working functions, that means:

Let's say I have function A call function B first and then function C, and function C calls function D. At time t = 1, B is running, so I want the stdout to be:

```
Root: function A -> running properly, called B
2-nd: function B -> running properly
```

At time t = 2, B has returned to A, so the stdout becomes:

```
Root: function A -> running properly, B returned
```

At time t = 3, A has called C. At time t = 4, C has called D. The stdout should be:

```
Root: function A -> running properly, B returned, called C
2-nd: function C -> running properly, called D
3-rd: function D -> running properly
```

At time t = 5, D returned. At time t = 6, C returned. The stdout should be:

```
Root: function A -> running properly, B returned, C returned
```

At time t = 7, function A returned:

```
Root: function A -> Done
```

Besides creating a logger object and passing it around, is there a more elegant way to automate this? What if A or B is a multithreaded process?

Any suggestions is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Have you looked at the `inspect` module?  You can already get the stack and a trace from there.

Comment: I have not seen it before. As I read it, perhaps it is usable. Yet I want a clean way of logging. If I use inspect, it seems like I have to call a set of functions to get info before every function calls. That would be the same as logger object, except this is built-in and great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [trace module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) within Python. You can generate annotated trace reports using this module

The definition of the **trace** module in the Python docs :

> The trace module allows you to trace program execution, generate annotated statement coverage listings, print caller/callee relationships and list functions executed during a program run. It can be used in another program or from the command line.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! Is it possible to modify the logging output before it prints by overriding any function? I didn't mention in my post, but I want the output to be flexible based on my need, which will become a second question later.

Comment: @Mai I am not completely sure if this can be done.Did some digging around and figured out this article that details how trace can be used for code coverage analysis and tracking calls : http://doughellmann.com/2008/10/pymotw-trace.html. I guess, the output of trace command itself can be parsed and rendered into the desired format?